# Bootstrap intervals for predictions, how to interpret it?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, prediction-interval, uncertainty

I want to come up with a way to get how confident I am in my predictions. I am not using a Bayesian model so I was thinking a bootstrap confidence interval would be good:

I would re-sample my original training set, train on it and predict. And repeat that n number of times. I would then gather the n predictions and I could get some bootstrap intervals on my prediction.

The way that I interpret that would be: the larger the interval, the more sensitive my prediction is to the variation in the training data, which would in turn mean that I am fairly uncertain about my prediction. The smaller the interval would mean the opposite.

The questions are:

1) Is this a sensible thing to do to start with?
2) Is there any other interpretation that could be made? In this case, it is not true that for a 95% interval say, I would expect my interval to contain the truth 95% of the time, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226565/bootstrap-prediction-interval and also see here https://www.emse.fr/~roustant/Documents/Bootstrap_Conf_and_Pred_Intervals.pdf

Comment: I feel like the post is too focused on the OLS case. It put my off at first but I guess the process can be generalized to arbitrary learning functions. Thanks for that link, some nice information on there.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, it is perfectly sensible.
2. For a quick interpretation, I like the one provided by Davison: Assuming $T$ is an estimator of a parameter $\psi$ based on a random sample $Y_1, . . . , Y_n$, $V_T^{0.5}$ is the standard error of $T$, $n \rightarrow \infty$  and $\zeta_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th quantile of a standard normal distribution function, the interval with endpoints: $T − \zeta_{1−\alpha} V_T^{0.5}, T + \zeta_{\alpha} V_T^{0.5}$ contains $\psi_0$, the true but unknown value of $\psi$, with probability approximately $(1 − 2\alpha)$. (See A.C. Davison [*"Statistical models"*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/statistical-models/8EC19F80551F52D4C58FAA2022048FC7), Chapt. 3 for more.)

These said, there are some insightful threads in CV as why this is a somewhat     over-simplified view of what a confidence interval is:
    "*[Why does a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) not imply a 95% chance of containing the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the/)*",
    "*[Interpretation of confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158570/interpretation-of-confidence-interval)*" and "*[Is it true that the percentile bootstrap should never be used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355781/is-it-true-that-the-percentile-bootstrap-should-never-be-used)*". 
    To quote Hastie et al. from the book "*[Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/)*" (Sect. 8.4) directly: "*we might think of the bootstrap distribution as a "poor man's" Bayes posterior. By perturbing the data, the bootstrap approximates the Bayesian effect of perturbing the parameters, and is typically much simpler to carry out.*"

When bootstrapping I think is much more important not to forget accounting for dependence structures (e.g. as described for example in Owen and Eckles' [*Bootstrapping data arrays of arbitrary order*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1346418567)). These might be due to clustering of the data, heteroskedasticity (e.g. see the notion of [*wild bootstrap*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407608000833)) and other deviations from IID data generating procedures. Ignoring such issues will render any discussions about the subsequent interpretation of the generated CIs, moot.

Comment: I think the focus on confidence intervals - rather than prediction intervals - might be misplaced.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your comment. I see why one may comment that but I think that when it comes to *bootstrap*-generated intervals the difference between the two is immaterial. Obviously PIs account for variance due to error terms and yes, we might want to use variance-adjusted residuals for a parametric bootstrap, but a simple non-parametric bootstrap (as described by the OP) is accounting for that during bootstrap estimation. The final statistic incorporates the error. (Apologies for the late reply, I was away for a while)